# Convert object to a function returning the same object and keep casting

Tags: typescript

I have this object:

```
const five: { amount: number } = {
  amount: 5,
}
```

I want it to convert it to a function that returns the same object, i.e.

```
const five = () => ({amount: 5})
```

How do re-use the casting so I can assure the response type?

Comment: Do you mean restrict the function to return the same type as original object?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `typeof` operator to query the object type:

```
const five: { amount: number } = {
    amount: 5,
}

const fiveFunc: () => typeof five = () => ({ amount: 1 });
```

With alias:

```
type FiveFunc = () => typeof five;

const fiveFunc: FiveFunc = () => ({ amount: 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think as i understand that you can do

```
const five: { amount: number } = {
  amount: 5,
}

let x=new Function()
{ () => ({amount: 5})}
```

please let me know if this what you are searching for :)